# Excel VBA 'Stack out of Space' when assigning named range for loop

Tags: excel, stack-overflow, vba

I'm getting a "Stack out of Space" error (28) when this code runs. Generally it crashes Excel altogether, but sometimes I'm able to 'Debug' immediately upon opening the worksheet.

When it does, the VBA editor highlights the `Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("M3:M61")` line.

I think the problem may be due to the fact that `"M3:M61"` range is actually a named range within an Excel table (as can be seen in the next line, 
    `'Set FormulaRange = Workbooks("Advance Request & Tracking Form rebuild.xlsm").Range("tbl_interface[Liquidation in]").RefersToRange`, which I have commented out because I can never get it to work.

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim countdownRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimit As Double
    Dim countdownFeedbackOffset As Double

    NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
    SentMsg = "Sent"

    'Below the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimit = 1

    'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
    Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("M3:M61")
    'Set FormulaRange = Workbooks("Advance Request & Tracking Form rebuild.xlsm").Range("tbl_interface[Liquidation in]").RefersToRange

    'MsgBox FormulaRange

    countdownFeedbackOffset = 2

    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
        With FormulaCell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Not numeric"
                MyMsg = "Not numeric"
            Else
                If .Value < MyLimit Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, countdownFeedbackOffset).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_adv_liq_reminder
                        'Call Mail_with_outlook1
                    End If
                Else
                    MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, countdownFeedbackOffset).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
         & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

It sort of boggles my mind that it could be choking on that - there are only actually 6 cells in that range that aren't blank - but I dunno what else it could be.

Comment: Are you sure that `Mail_adv_liq_reminder` isn't the culprit? Your problem is not reproducible, hence it is hard for others to do any more than guess what it is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could try `Application.EnableEvents = False` as the very first line of the event handler. This will prevent a cascade of event-handler calls, which might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Not numeric"` could be triggering a calculation, even if there are no cells which explicitly refer to it. Perhaps you have some volatile formulas. You seem to be aware of the danger of an infinite regress since you use `Application.EnableEvents = False`, but only in one branch of the code. What is almost certainly the case is that other branches of the code are triggering calculations. Another possibility (for all I know) is that the sub `Mail_adv_liq_reminder` somehow triggers a calculation as a side effect. The fact that the line `Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("M3:M61")` is more likely than not a symptom rather than a cause. The attempt to do that assignment just happens to be the straw that breaks the camel's back.

The solution is to have an unconditional `Application.EnableEvents = False` as the first line of the event handler (setting it back equal to true at the end).

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Since I'm trying to adapt code I found elsewhere, the presence of the Application.EnableEvents = False line just reflects the wisdom of whomever wrote the original code (probably Rob de Bruin), not depth of insight on my part.